# ID gets passed in QueryString bt when I store in session it is stored as '0'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET project for my final year and am presently working on the "Admin" module and am stuck in this part of code given below.I am fetching the object of "Service" through the method "SelectByID(int id)" in by Business Logic. This method returns an object of "Service". Now when I store this object into a Session and look at the properties of the object, the ID is stored as '0'. and I need this ID in another method of the same page where I am changing the display picture via FileUploadControl. I am attaching the code of my method,C# code of method, and a screen shot of the object's properties.

```
<pre><code>public Service SelectByID(int ServiceID) 
        {
            string query = "select * from tblService where ServiceID=@ServiceID ";
            List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", ServiceID));

            DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, lstParams);

            Service serviceObj = new Service();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                serviceObj.Name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                serviceObj.Description = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
                serviceObj.Photo = dt.Rows[0]["Photo"].ToString();
            }

            return serviceObj;

        }

//Page Load Code 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["admin"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ServiceLogic serviceLogic = new ServiceLogic();
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]); // Here ID is recieved properly from QueryString
                Service service = serviceLogic.SelectByID(id); //Here too ID is recieved(obviously)
                Session["service"] = service; //Here the ServiceID is storing  '0'
                lblService.Text = service.Name;
                txtServiceName.Text = service.Name;
                txtDescription.Text = service.Description;

                if (service.Photo == "")
                {
                    imgService.ImageUrl = "~/Images/defaultVendor.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    imgService.ImageUrl = service.Photo;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
        }


    }

//Update profile pic code. Assume the above code where file extensions and file size are checked!
                  {
                    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/ServicesPhoto/" + fuServiceImage.FileName);
                    fuServiceImage.SaveAs(filePath);

                    lblServiceUpdate.Text = "Display Picture Changed Successfully!";
                    lblServiceUpdate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                    string imagePath = "~/Images/ProfilePics/" + fuServiceImage.FileName;
                    imgService.ImageUrl = imagePath;

                    Service service = (Service)Session["service"];

                    serviceLogic.updateServiceImage(imagePath, service.ServiceID);
                    service.Photo = imagePath;

                    lblService.Text = service.Name;
                    txtServiceName.Text = service.Name;
                    txtDescription.Text = service.Description;
                    imgService.ImageUrl = service.Photo;
                    //Response.Redirect("ServiceDetails.aspx");
           }
```

Comment: Sorry i could not add the ScreenShot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch ID from Service Method

```
public Service SelectByID(int ServiceID) 
    {
        string query = "select * from tblService where ServiceID=@ServiceID ";
        List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

        lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", ServiceID));

        DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, lstParams);

        Service serviceObj = new Service();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            serviceObj.ID = dt.Rows[0]["ServiceID"].ToString();
            serviceObj.Name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            serviceObj.Description = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
            serviceObj.Photo = dt.Rows[0]["Photo"].ToString();
        }

        return serviceObj;

    }
```

Add ID object in Service Data Get Method

```
 serviceObj.ID = dt.Rows[0]["ServiceID"].ToString();
```

Comment: i dont have any idea, about how to mark it resolved! Help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not fetching and storing Id into the Service object.

Try the below method:

```
    public Service SelectByID(int ServiceID) 
    {


        string query = "select * from tblService where ServiceID=@ServiceID ";
        List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

        lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", ServiceID));

        DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, lstParams);

        Service serviceObj = new Service();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            serviceObj.ID = dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();

            // Or you can use
            // serviceObj.ID = ServiceID;
            serviceObj.Name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            serviceObj.Description = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
            serviceObj.Photo = dt.Rows[0]["Photo"].ToString();
        }

        return serviceObj;

    }
```

Please do not forget to mark if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, please mark it as resolved so I can get some points also. Thanks.